# Query problems (SELECT)

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

I am trying to do a query that counts the number of games that a player has participated. The player is stored in a ID.

The game participants are stored in a list of integers to json like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OszSN.png

The thing I am trying to do is to select the count of games that it participated and `INNER JOIN` the ID in a other table that has this structure:

**NOTE: The time must be in the latest 30 days!**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1aeK.png

I am trying to return the `nick`column and the count of games that every id participated.

In order to do it, I started with a `SELECT` with an `INNER JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause to see if `end` was >= than the currentMills. I also need to order by all this things.

So the first print would give something like this:

imagine that there is only the id number 1 in the table and the participants are [1,2]

This is what I need

```
ID (Converted to **\`nick\`** with INNER JOIN) | COUNT 
["LucaAzalim"] | 1 
["Teste", "JoaoRatao", "\_Pik0\_"] | 1
```

Comment: What DB do you use (MySQL,...)?

Comment: Please don't post sample data as links to images. Add formatted(!) text instead. And please add the tag for your DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, ...). The support for JSON is extremely different between different DBMS

Comment: I am new to this forum so I didnt know the best way to make a post. I use MySQL